# I was trying to implement SOLID Principles. this time Dependency inversion in Python - Django

Tags: python, django, abstract-class, solid-principles, inversion

TypeError: SignInView.init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'api_response_factory'

I try to use abstract methods but it failed. I'm new about SOLID implementation and new in python too, can someone give me an advice or idea about how to deal with this kind of erros?

I have to add that this is my first time asking in stackoverflow

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import status

class ApiResponseFactoryAbstract(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def success(self) -> str:
        pass

class ApiResponseFactory(ApiResponseFactoryAbstract):
    def success(self) -> str:
        print("Testing")
        return "Testing"

class SignInView(APIView):
    def __init__(self, api_response_factory: ApiResponseFactoryAbstract):
        self.api_response_factory = api_response_factory

    def post(self, request):
        data = self.api_response_factory.success()
        return JsonResponse(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is app/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

router_auth = [
    path("sign-in/", views.SignInView.as_view(), name="sign-in"),
]
```

Comment: You can not add an arbitrary parameter to the initializer of an `APIView`.

Comment: what do you mean about "arbitrary"? I would like to understand better, thanks

Comment: @SignInView: where exactly do you specifh *what* to pass to the `api_response_factory` in the `SignInView`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't get your question, sorry, that's all code I need and I have to this part, what you see is what I have and those are parameters i send to each class. Im changing from PHP to Python and trying to understand how abstract works here, I got interfaces in PHP and everything was "easier" in that way.

Comment: The error implies that you call `SigninView()` somewhere, but you need to pass a `api_response_factory` to that constructor.

Comment: @Robert my code is updated

Comment: I don't know Django, so I'm just guessing here: Change `views.SignInView.as_view()` to `views.SignInView(ApiResponseFactory()).as_view()`. That way you pass the required object to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work: the `.as_view()` will for each request construct a *new* `SignInView` object, to handle the request. But it thus does not pass an object.

Luckely we can. Indeed, we can pass one in the initkwargs with:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

router_auth = [
    path(
        'sign-in/',
        views.SignInView.as_view(api_response_factory=ApiResponseFactory()),
        name='sign-in',
    ),
]
```

that being said, I don't see the need for this. It is probably easier to work with a *mixin* that provides with implementations for success messages, etc. It looks a bit like *over-engineering*.